# SSIS Parse Json

Tags: c#, .net, ssis, json.net

I am trying to parse a json inside an SSIS package with a script component.

I have 
-  MVS 2017 (SSDT)
-  MS Visual C# 2017, 
-  .NET Framework 4.5

[image]

The NuGet Manager suggests the Newtosoft.Json V: 9.0.1 as the latest.

[image]

After instelling it I use the following code to test the task :

```
        dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{ 'betType': 'Jon Smith'}");
```

And I get the error:

```
  System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0 ...
```

Also., in the solution explorer of the script component under the references the Version of the Newtonsoft.Json is 9.0.0.0.

[image]

I tried to reinstall the package but it didn't work.  Also no later version is available through the nuget manager.

Comment: Basically create classes to match your JSON as this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp

Comment: @KeithL thank you for your answer. so you suggest to use the JavaScriptSerializer() ?

Comment: What happens if you change Copy Local from False to True?

Comment: I always use it. I typically work in environments where 3rd party tools are not allowed (netwonsoft in your case)

Comment: @KeithL Thank You for the helo .it worked